# Unique constraint violation found when editing category Name / URL key in 2.4.3 / having url_path

Tags: url-rewrite, magento2.4.3

We are getting errors like

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'themen/redacted/redacted.html-1' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT  INTO `url_rewrite` (`redirect_type`,`is_autogenerated`,`metadata`,`description`,`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`request_path`,`target_path`,`store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (
```

with 8000 params in the SQL when updating a single category.

Are there still known issues in Magento 2.4.3 concering URL rewrites? How can this be debugged and fixed?

For debugging I replaced `\Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql::_execute`

```
public function _execute(array $params = null)
{
    $specialExecute = false;
    if ($params) {
        foreach ($params as $param) {
            if ($param instanceof Parameter) {
                $specialExecute = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($specialExecute) {
        return $this->_executeWithBinding($params);
    } else {
        try {
            return $this->tryExecute(function () use ($params) {
                return $params !== null ? $this->_stmt->execute($params) : $this->_stmt->execute();
            });
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            if (strpos($e->getMessage(), 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID') !== false) {
                $keys = [];
                foreach(range(0,(count($params) / 9) -1) as $index) {
                    $keys[] = $params[$index * 9 + 6] . '-' . $params[$index * 9 + 8];
                }

            }


            throw new \Exception('Key list:' . PHP_EOL . implode(PHP_EOL, $keys) . PHP_EOL,0,$e);
        }
    }
}
```

This shows duplicates with the same words but once with a capital letter, once lower case.

EDIT:

### First problem solved, new problem arises

We deleted URL paths and regenerated all URLs using
https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls, this fixes the first problem. but now we get

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '51541850' for key 'PRIMARY', query was:
INSERT  INTO `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` 
(`url_rewrite_id`,`category_id`,`product_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)
```

#### Debugging

The above error is caused in [`\Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Product::saveMultiple`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.3/app/code/Magento/CatalogUrlRewrite/Model/ResourceModel/Category/Product.php#L52) which is called by `\Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Category\Plugin\Storage::afterReplace` and is an interceptor of `\Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlPersistInterface::replace`

The question I ask myself is: It's intercepting a replace call, but actually it is inserting the keys to the `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` table - not using a replace into - is this a logic bug in the current Magento version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query helped here, after the upgrade:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33770#issuecomment-991065898

```
START TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE catalog_url_rewrite_product_category_temp
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM catalog_url_rewrite_product_category;
ALTER TABLE catalog_url_rewrite_product_category RENAME catalog_url_rewrite_product_category_backup;
ALTER TABLE catalog_url_rewrite_product_category_temp RENAME catalog_url_rewrite_product_category;
DROP TABLE catalog_url_rewrite_product_category_backup;
COMMIT;
```